# A directed graph on sets of primes

Tags: graph-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the directed graph whose vertices are non-empty finite sets of primes, where the number of arcs from $S$ to $T$ equals the number of integers $n>1$ for which the set of prime divisors of $n$ is $S$ and the set of prime divisors of $n+1$ is $T$. Thus for example there is an edge from {5,7} to {2,3} because of how 35 and 36 factorize. There are edges in both directions between {2} and {3}; in fact there are two edges from {2} to {3} because of $n=2$ and $n=8$ and an edge from {3} to {2} because of $n=3$. It’s a pleasant pastime to find edges from one small set of primes to another. It’s also easy to see that this directed graph is bipartite, where the vertices are bicolored according to whether or not the set contains 2. In particular, there cannot be an edge between {$p$} and {$q$} when $p$ and $q$ are odd primes.

Has this directed graph (or the associated undirected graph) been studied? Are any of its gross properties known? I emphasize the word “gross”: questions about specific sets $S$ and $T$ are likely to be hard (like Catalan’s conjecture which was only resolved 20 years ago). But statistical properties might be tractable if only as consequences of the RH.

E.g., can one prove (or heuristically argue) that the associated undirected graph has infinite diameter?

Postscript, added January 25, 2022: There are exactly 22 integers $n$ between 2 and $10^9$ such that both $n$ and $n+1$ have no prime factor bigger than 7, of which the largest is 4374; if there are no larger $n$ with this property, as seems likely, then the induced (directed) sub-multigraph given by the subsets of {2,3,5,7} has the following edges: ({2},{3}) (twice), ({2},{5}), ({3},{2}), ({3},{2,5}), ({3},{2,7}), ({5},{2,3}), ({5},{2,3,7}), ({7},{2}), ({7},{2,5}), ({2,3},{5}), ({2,3},{7}) (twice), ({2,3},{5,7}), ({2,5},{3}), ({2,5},{3,7}), ({2,7},{3,5}) (twice), ({3,5},{2}), ({3,7},{2}), ({5,7},{2,3}), and ({2,3,5},{7}). Another interesting question is whether there are infinitely many edges with multiplicity bigger than 1.

Comment: Does multiplicity of the edges matter at all to you? If so, you should perhaps clarify you are talking about (directed) *multi*graphs. At any rate, one thing we can say is that the multiplicity is always finite, by Siegel's finiteness result for $S$-unit equations.

Comment: "questions about specific sets S and T are likely to be hard" quite the opposite - for any two specific sets $S,T$ we have very explicit and fairly efficient ways of finding all solutions to $a-b=1$, where $a$ is only divisible by primes in $S$ and $b$ only by primes in $T$. Again, the key word is "$S$-unit equation".

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes on both counts! Thanks for your comments; now I know more than I did before.

Comment: This is relevant to the Pratt trees mentioned in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/413472